# Use arrows keys to call Lispy functions

Tags: key-bindings, smartparens, paredit

In `lispy-mode`, I want to use control + the arrow keys instead of `lispy`'s defaults (`h`, `j`, `k`, `l`).

But if I run the obvious code

```
     (define-key lispy-mode-map [C-up] 'lispy-up)
```

then `C-up` always calls `lispy-up`.  This is unlike `lispy`'s defaults, which are only available when one is right next to a parenthesis.

How do I make control + the arrows to operate exactly as `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`?

Comment: Maybe look at the `lispy.el` code, to see what kind of bindings it makes, and do the same? Are those keys bound in a mode map, perhaps?

Comment: Try `C-h k h` when in lispy mode to see what function is bound to key `h`.

Comment: @JeanPierre: interestingly, `h` does not call `lispy-left` but `special-lispy-left`, which calls `lispy-left` (when in the right position) or self inserts, otherwise.  The problem is that `C-up` does not do anything when self inserted.  I'm guessing the solution will be to write my own `special-lispy-left`, which will call `lispy-left` or `left-word`.

Comment: Indeed.  I hope at some point emacs will provide some more convenient way to do that (sort of a keymap that binds a (key, context) to a command) since such "context based" bindings are becoming  very common (org-mode uses that a lot).